# F# Read File, Split string list, summarize data, Nonfloat decimal numbers

Tags: function, f#, split

I'm new to F# and got this assignment to create a very simple bankrepresentation.
I do not want any code answers directly related to the problem, but preferally links or tips on where to find solutions or how to find do the solutions.

The issues are the following:

- Reading lines of a file (a line looks like this: "126,145001,1500.00" and it's sequence_number, account_number, amount)
- Split the line to use the data from the line
- summarize the data (to return the bank account balance)
- Not using floating point numbers representing the amount, due to rounding errors(?)
- Doing all of these in one function.

I know how to read a file, in a function.
I also know how to split a string.
I know how to recursivly add values from a list.

I do not know how to add values that are decimal without floating-point variables.
I do not know how to retrieve the string from a list in a function and split it.
I do not know how to do all of these things in on function taking in file name, account number, and account currency.

The function should return the balance after the transactions in the file have been proccessed.

My idea to solve this is to create a datatype that have the three variables sequence_number,   account_number and amount, and then do the following:
Read the file,
Split the data and create an object of my custom type for each line in the file
Add and remove the values from the types and return the final balance.

If anyone could point me in the right direction for each or any problem I would be really thankful!

Comment: Your data looks like `CSV`. Have a look at http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvProvider.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET contains a type called `System.Decimal` that is indeed more appropriate for storing financial figures than the typical floating point types.  In F#, you can use the `decimal` function to convert a value of a different type (say a string) to a `System.Decimal` (which F# abbreviates as a type also named `decimal`): `let d = decimal "1.23"`  You can also create these values directly by using the `M` suffix: `let d' = 1.23M`, but in your case that doesn't seem relevant.

Regarding your other questions, if you use `System.IO.File.ReadLines`, then you can get the individual lines of your file as a sequence.  Then you can string together a bunch of operations on that sequence to achieve your desired result.  For instance, you can take the sequence and use `Seq.map <your splitting code here>` to split each line (and convert to instances of your specific data type, if desired), and then use `Seq.groupBy` to group the transactions by account number, and then `Seq.map` again to apply your summarization logic to each group.  Ask follow-up questions if any of this is unclear.

Comment: I passed the assignment, but I was told to learn how types like this are stored in the memory. I know ints are stored precisely using sequences of bits, but floats for example are stored in the memory as sequences of exponentials. I don't know if it is exactly correct what Im saying, but none the less, could you tell me how the representation of a Decimal is different from Float, or if none, how  they are stored. 
The representation in the memory with floats are not exact, since there are no exponentials that in binary can define certain numbers?
Any clarification would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @PontusMagnusson - check out the remarks on the [MSDN page for the System.Decimal type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal(v=vs.110).aspx).  Basically, decimals are floating point numbers, but using base 10 instead of base 2 (but read the page I cited for the full details).